# MySQL replication with read/write tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication

I'm trying to implement replicas between master database and secondary databases. I've tried binary replication - it works as suggested. But I want use some service to manage this without manual actions.

DigitalOcean has a service called Managed Databases but it offers just read-only nodes:

> Read-only nodes are copies of the primary node that process queries
> and return results but cannot make changes to the database itself.
> They provide geographically distinct, horizontal read scaling.
> Read-only nodes can be added to a cluster at any time

The problem is secondary DB has tables I have to use for writing. Is there any managed DB services that I could use to accomplish this idea?

Master DB structure sample

```
main_tbl_1
main_tbl_2
main_tbl_3
```

Secondary DB structure sample

```
main_tbl_1
main_tbl_2
main_tbl_3
secondary_tbl_1
secondary_tbl_2
...
```

Another way is to use two DB connections for master and secondary.

Comment: I don't know about managed DB services for this, but you can accomplish what you want with so-called master-master replication which is really master-secondary replication from node1 to node2 combined with master-secondary replication from node2 to node1, and then use replication filters to specify which tables should/should not be replicated.

Comment: @dbdemon your comment looks like an answer

Comment: Is DO's offering based on Galera or InnoDB Cluster?  Or do they have their own hands-off HA support?